# pseConvert an Android app to IOS app using Cordova (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have just finished an app in Eclipse using Cordova 2.9.0.

The app is JavaScript / HTML / CSS based.

Can anyone recommend software / a forum which had good tutorials on converting apps from Android to IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap gives you the possibility to write once and use it for different platform Android, IOS ...

Create a progect with phonegap/cordova and add 2 platforms Android and IOS. Develop your app in root www directory. To specify different style, .js, html simply use directory merge.

Let say you need a different css for Android and IOS. In directory merge you have to have:
/merge/android/mycss.css and for IOS you have: /merge/ios/mycss.css

Look into Command-line Api of Cordova, search for "Using merges to Customize Each Platform". Here is the [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_using_merges_to_customize_each_platform)